# Fiddle IT - Instant Fiddles Userscript

Tags: script, stackoverflow

## Fiddle-IT

> A tiny & simple userscript for creating fiddles in seconds.
>
> Very handy for answering questions when you want to test the OP's code

---

### Usage

Select some code on the page, then press one of the following:

- HTML - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
- CSS    - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- JS        - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

To add the jQuery library to your fiddle, press the following:

- jQuery - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

To activate your fiddle, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

### Customizing

To add new libraries, you can do this inside the `keyup` event listener

```
if( event.keyCode === yourNewNumber ) return setLibrary('mootools', '1.0');
```

Check the libraries in JSFiddle for more info.

### Demo

I made a quick demo video for you to watch: [YouTube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TE5oHYNYXJQ) (make sure you have annotations on).

---

### Download

## [User Script](https://github.com/connorGFX/Fiddle-IT/raw/master/fiddle-it.user.js)

## [GitHub](https://github.com/connorGFX/Fiddle-IT/raw/master/fiddle-it.user.js)